# Bluebird Promise becomes resolved in any case

Tags: promise, mocha.js, bluebird

I must be doing something wrong, however this is my testcase:

```
const { describe, it } = require('mocha'),
  should = require('should'),
  Promise = require('bluebird') //v3.4.6
describe('Bluebird', () => {
  it('Promise is never resolved but does it get resolved?', () => {
    new Promise(() => false)
      .should.be.fulfilled() // It really shouldn't be
  })
})
```

This **passes**, but shouldn't it fail?

Comment: why do you have the double assert? the resulting promise handling a `reject` is a resolve.

Comment: @DanielA.White `.rejectedWith` will *pass*, but I noticed that the promise is also **resolved**, that's what this test case demonstrates. There are no chained Promises here

Comment: i would look at how mocha looks at the state of the promise.

Comment: @PeteV. is this server side code or client side?

Comment: Looks like a bug with `should` by the way, but there is really no need to write tests this way anymore.

Comment: You should probably `return` the Promise

Comment: @OliverSalzburg from `it()`?

Comment: @PeteV. Yes. https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises

Comment: @OliverSalzburg thank you, that was it. Would you like to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with promises in mocha tests, it is important to [`return` the promise](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises) from the test.

In your case, that would be:

```
it('Promise is never resolved but does it get resolved?', () => {
   return new Promise(() => false)
    .should.be.fulfilled()
})
```

However, that is probably still not exactly what you need here, as the fulfillment of the promise can't be determined at the time `should` is invoked. Your actual test is probably different, the most important part is still to return the promise chain.

When you do that, then you don't need to further assert the fulfillment/rejection of the promise, as that is done implicitly by mocha.

I'm personally a big fan of [chai-as-promised](https://github.com/domenic/chai-as-promised), which would allow you to use the exact same test you had before, but this time, it would be working.

Comment: Thank you. `should` does handle the asynchronicity like `chai-as-promised`

Comment: @PeteV. Ah, I didn't know that. Great :)